# how do I eject a SD card hooked up on the SPI port?

Tags: sd-card, spi

I have a **SD card reader hooked up to SPI0 on a RPi3.** I followed this post: https://ralimtek.com/raspberry%20pi/electronics/software/raspberry_pi_secondary_sd_card/

My devicetree file is pretty standard:

```
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/ {
   compatible = "brcm,bcm2835", "brcm,bcm2836", "brcm,bcm2708", "brcm,bcm2709";

   fragment@0 {
      target = <&spi0>;
      frag0: __overlay__ {
         status = "okay";
         sd1 {
                reg = <0>;
                status = "okay";
                compatible = "spi,mmc_spi";
                voltage-ranges = <3000 3500>;
                spi-max-frequency = <8000000>;
         };
      };
   };
};
```

And so is the `dtoverlay` in `/boot/config.txt`:

```
dtoverlay=mmc_spi
```

When I insert a card in the reader it get detected just fine. Accessing the card works as expected. I can mount it and access files.

Then I `umount` and do kinda expect that I need to do an `eject` of sort. But I cant figure out **how to eject the card properly before removing it physically**.

Needless to say, inserting a card again, same or different, it does not get detected. And the following over-optimistic mount of course go haywire.

Comment: Ah well, I found an ugly workaround, remove end reinsert the `mmc_spi` module. I am absolutely not a fan, but it seems to work

Comment: Please create an answer with the solution and accept it after two days. Only accepting an answer will finish the question and it will not pop up again and again for years.